# Oracle Timestamp to Unix Epoch Timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, oracle, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I've got an oracle Database with an `TIMESTAMP (6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` column that returns me values like this:

`20-FEB-12 11.41.17.799000 AM`

How can i parse those into a normal unix timestamp in PHP?
`strtotime()` doesn't work (returns false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found i can use `TO_CHAR` to turn the Timestamp into something more parseable within the database query.

There is a description here: http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html